# how do i hide and show the text at a particular screen width using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

i am trying to remove a text from html when it reaches a particular screen width i only want to hide the text "Color mode " when the screen width is below 980px and i want to show the text above the that screen width. I'm able to remove the text when it reaches to 980px but i want to show the text when the screen width is above 980px. here is my code

how can i make the text visible when it is above 980px?

```js
let darkMode = document.querySelector("header div.night-mode");
const hamburger = document.querySelector("header nav div.hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector("header nav ul");
let darkModeMax = window.matchMedia("(max-width:980px)");
let darkModeMin = window.matchMedia("(min-width:981px)");
function mobileMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}
hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);
darkMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let body = document.body;
    body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a i").classList.toggle("fa-sun");
    document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").classList.toggle("dark-mode-color");
    document.querySelector("header h1 a").classList.toggle("dark-mode-color");
});
darkModeMax.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
    document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").innerText = "";
});
darkModeMin.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").innerText = "Color mode";
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:1100px;
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
header section.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'robotoblack';
}
header h1 a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    transition: 500ms linear;
}
header h1 a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
header h1 a:hover {
    color: #f8c145;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}
header nav {

}
header nav ul {
    display: flex;
}
header nav ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family: 'open_sansbold';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 21px;
}
header nav ul li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
header nav ul li a {
    color: #818181;
    height: 1.3em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header nav ul li a::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    color: #f8c145;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
header nav ul li a::before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    color: #818181;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
} 
header nav ul li a:hover::before {
    transform: translateY(-1.5em);
}
  
header nav ul li a:hover::after {
    transform: translateY(-1.5em);
}
header nav div.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

header nav div.hamburger span.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #101010;
}
header div.night-mode {
    font-family: 'robotoblack';
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
header div.night-mode a {

}
header div.night-mode a i {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 32px;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
.dark-mode {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
@media all and (max-width:640px) {
    header nav ul {
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
        top: 5rem;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }
    header nav ul.active {
        left: 0;
    }
    header nav ul li {
        margin: 2.5rem 0;
    }
    header nav div.hamburger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <header>
              <section class="wrapper">
                  <h1>
                      <a href="#"><i class="far fa-user"></i>Marvel</a>
                  </h1>
                  <nav class="navbar">
                      <ul class="nav-menu" >
                          <li class="nav-item" ><a data-text="About" href="#spotlight" class="nav-link" ></a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item" ><a data-text="Projects" href="#show-case" class="nav-link" ></a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item" ><a data-text="Resume" href="#resume" class="nav-link" ></a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item" ><a data-text="Contact" href="#contacts" class="nav-link" ></a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="hamburger">
                          <span class="bar"></span>
                          <span class="bar"></span>
                          <span class="bar"></span>
                      </div>
                  </nav>
                  <div class="night-mode">
                      <a href="#"><i class="far fa-moon"></i>Color mode</a>
                  </div>
              </section>
          </header>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no need for javascript here. Just use a @media rule to set `display: block` or `display: none`. You're already doing that exact thing for your header.

Comment: display block will hide my icon too. actually there is a moon icon adjacent to the text "Color mode" i want to hide the text when its is below 980px but i don't want hide the moon icon.

Comment: So put the text in a <span> and hide just the <span>.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah that's pretty good solution bro thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a media query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #colorModeText {
    display: none; /*Won't be displayed on screens below or equal to 980px width*/
  }
}
```

And put the text 'Color Mode' in a `<span>` tag
Then, give the `<span>` tag an id of **colorModeText** like:

```
<span id="colorModeText">Color Mode</span>
```

Comment: That work's brother Thank's :)

Answer (score 1):

Slove via CSS like this
add  tag for that text and put id for this element

```
<a href="#" class="">
    <i class="far fa-moon"></i>
    <span  id="nightModeDiv">Color mode</span>
</a>
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #nightModeDiv {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```js
let darkMode = document.querySelector("header div.night-mode");
const hamburger = document.querySelector("header nav div.hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector("header nav ul");
let darkModeMax = window.matchMedia("(max-width:980px)");
let darkModeMin = window.matchMedia("(min-width:981px)");
function mobileMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}
hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);
darkMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let body = document.body;
    body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a i").classList.toggle("fa-sun");
    document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").classList.toggle("dark-mode-color");
    document.querySelector("header h1 a").classList.toggle("dark-mode-color");
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:1100px;
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
header section.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'robotoblack';
}
header h1 a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    transition: 500ms linear;
}
header h1 a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
header h1 a:hover {
    color: #f8c145;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}
header nav {

}
header nav ul {
    display: flex;
}
header nav ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family: 'open_sansbold';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 21px;
}
header nav ul li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
header nav ul li a {
    color: #818181;
    height: 1.3em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header nav ul li a::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    color: #f8c145;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
header nav ul li a::before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    color: #818181;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
} 
header nav ul li a:hover::before {
    transform: translateY(-1.5em);
}
  
header nav ul li a:hover::after {
    transform: translateY(-1.5em);
}
header nav div.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

header nav div.hamburger span.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #101010;
}
header div.night-mode {
    font-family: 'robotoblack';
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
header div.night-mode a {

}
header div.night-mode a i {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 32px;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
.dark-mode {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
@media all and (max-width:640px) {
    header nav ul {
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
        top: 5rem;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }
    header nav ul.active {
        left: 0;
    }
    header nav ul li {
        margin: 2.5rem 0;
    }
    header nav div.hamburger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #nightModeDiv {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <header>
              <section class="wrapper">
                  <h1>
                      <a href="#"><i class="far fa-user"></i>Marvel</a>
                  </h1>
                  <nav class="navbar">
                      <ul class="nav-menu" >
                          <li class="nav-item" ><a data-text="About" href="#spotlight" class="nav-link" ></a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item" ><a data-text="Projects" href="#show-case" class="nav-link" ></a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item" ><a data-text="Resume" href="#resume" class="nav-link" ></a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item" ><a data-text="Contact" href="#contacts" class="nav-link" ></a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="hamburger">
                          <span class="bar"></span>
                          <span class="bar"></span>
                          <span class="bar"></span>
                      </div>
                  </nav>
                  <div class="night-mode">
                      <a href="#" class=""><i class="far fa-moon"></i><span  id="nightModeDiv">Color mode</span></a>
                  </div>
              </section>
          </header>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it will hide my "moon" icon too i don't want to hide my icon.

Comment: Now check the answer

Comment: Yeah now it's works Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Just use `window.addEventListener` and pass the `resize` event. And
> you'll have to compare `window.innerWidth` with the exact width you
> want to select.

Check the below approach

```
   window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 980) {
        document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").innerText = "";
      } else {
        document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").innerText = "Color mode";
      }
   });
```

```js
let darkMode = document.querySelector("header div.night-mode");
const hamburger = document.querySelector("header nav div.hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector("header nav ul");

function mobileMenu() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
  navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}
hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);
darkMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let body = document.body;
  body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a i").classList.toggle("fa-sun");
  document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").classList.toggle("dark-mode-color");
  document.querySelector("header h1 a").classList.toggle("dark-mode-color");
});

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  if (window.innerWidth < 980) {
    document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").innerText = "";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("header div.night-mode a").innerText = "Color mode";
  }
}
);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header section.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: 'robotoblack';
}

header h1 a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  transition: 500ms linear;
}

header h1 a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

header h1 a:hover {
  color: #f8c145;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}

header nav {}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-family: 'open_sansbold';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 21px;
}

header nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #818181;
  height: 1.3em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header nav ul li a::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: #f8c145;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

header nav ul li a::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: #818181;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

header nav ul li a:hover::before {
  transform: translateY(-1.5em);
}

header nav ul li a:hover::after {
  transform: translateY(-1.5em);
}

header nav div.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

header nav div.hamburger span.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #101010;
}

header div.night-mode {
  font-family: 'robotoblack';
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header div.night-mode a {}

header div.night-mode a i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 32px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.dark-mode {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

@media all and (max-width:640px) {
  header nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: 5rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }
  header nav ul.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  header nav ul li {
    margin: 2.5rem 0;
  }
  header nav div.hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  header nav div.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <h1>
        <a href="#"><i class="far fa-user"></i>Marvel</a>
      </h1>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-text="About" href="#spotlight" class="nav-link"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-text="Projects" href="#show-case" class="nav-link"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-text="Resume" href="#resume" class="nav-link"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-text="Contact" href="#contacts" class="nav-link"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hamburger">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="night-mode">
        <a href="#"><i class="far fa-moon"></i>Color mode</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```